# Getting Random NoClassDefFoundError In Test Results

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I run TestNG tests daily on Jenkins using Maven. I rarely (seems random as well) get a NoClassDefFoundError. If I rerun the test it usually passes normally. It seems to be happening when I pass `ClassName.class` as an argument to a method.

It is thrown for different classes, but always when calling this method:

```
// page object for selenium
// line 166 in stack trace below
Page.getObject(webDriver, PageClass.class);
```

So in this case the error would be:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/PageClass
```

But like I said, PageClass can differ.

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/PageClass
path.to.DifferentPageClass.someMethod(DifferentPageClass.java:166)
path.to.LibClass.someMethod(LibClass.java:132)
path.to.SuiteClass.testMethod(SuiteClass.java:332)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:200)
com.bigweb.weather.test.utility.BaseTest.run(BaseTest.java:88)
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:212)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:689)
org.testng.internal.Invoker.retryFailed(Invoker.java:1027)
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:95)
org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:14)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

How can I find the root cause of this?

Comment: In general, it means that the named class is found, but that there is something wrong with it.  Occasionally if you look at the stack trace you will notice that there is another error listed farther "down" the trace, in which case that error is the likely cause.  Otherwise, mismatched jar files are the most common cause.

Comment: This is the full trace, no other errors. This is also a class of my own, I run `mvn test`. So jars wouldn't be the cause right?

Comment: This class is also used in many other tests, for example in this case, 5/1022 tests failed and all 5 were due to this error. All 5 were also the exact same test method (with different input params). I would say ~150 other tests use this same page class and had no issues.

Comment: The other common problem is having a mismatch between the full name of the class file and the name of the class contained therein, including the package name.  "path.to.PageClass" must be contained in a file located at "path/to/PageClass.class" in the directory structure and contain `package path.to;`.

Comment: Like I said, it seems to rarely happen. In the last 14 test runs, it happened in 2 tests. The other 12 were fine. Would it happen everytime if it were a mismatch?

Comment: Finally, this can occur because you edited a class (not necessarily the named one) and recompiled it, but didn't recompile all the other classes that reference it.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks for the help. I will let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: Oddly I have not seen this recently. I am not sure how it was resolved :(

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this before because a test broke and all others tests become compromised and didn't work.

I don't know pretty much about your environment. So, I'll try some steps:

- Take a look at your surefire report to see where the first test breaks/fail and work on it.
- Make sure that all test are executing. (Maven has a convention, that all test classes need finish your name with the word "Test". (e.g. MyClassTest))
- Look the scope of dependency of your class. It must be "compile" or at least "test". If it's not specified, specify it. You can't trust in Maven everytime.
- Make sure that your jenkins environment can download dependencies. (if you have a proxy)